# Why 'terraform apply' is trying to destroy everything else in the workspace?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a separate repo for storing some of the new terraform scripts (the definition of a lambda and a S3 bucket which linked to the lambda), I have some infrastructures defined in a different repo for the same workspace.

When I run `Terraform apply` it's trying to detroy everything else defined in the other repo and add the new infrastructures defined in this repo, why is this? How can I keep all of them?

I found that the state stored on my local machine is `version 3` whereas the state stored in S3 bucket shows `version 4`, and the content is different, could this be the issue?

Comment: You run the terraform scripts from locally?

Comment: How are you configuring your state? It sounds like you are trying to use the same state file for both directories.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR The states file are stored in a separate bucket, I have two projects in the dev stack, I compared the state files betwwen those two projects, they're completely the same, I also found one in my local machine, I'm new to Terraform, not sure what to do....

Comment: It sounds like you are using state wrong but it's going to be hard to work out exactly what you are doing wrong in the context of a Q & A here. You'd probably be best off following through the documentation and guides on the Terraform website about how state works and how you should be running things.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Thanks, I've been doing some research about this, one thing I found strange is that the state on my local machine is different from the others, I think I'm supposed to use the one stored remotely instead of the current one (because the one stored in S3 bucket has some shared resources)

Comment: I tried to replace the one stored on my local machine with the state (the one stored in S3), it says ```Error: Failed to load state: Terraform 0.12.20 does not support state version 4, please update.```

Comment: From the last Error you posted, it seems that you are using a state that was created with an older terraform version. In any case, try to not overcomplicate stuff with terraform, especially if you are new to it. To be honest, I don't quite understand your question. Why would you have 2 repos for the same workspace? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: it's just because I want to implement some separate stuff, I made it work before but not sure why this time it doesn't work...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the [import function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/usage.html) to import those resources into your state if you don't manage to fix the state version differences.

```
$ terraform import aws_instance.example i-abcd1234
```

Comment: But why should I? Shouldn't Terraform just automatically keep the two projects separate and unaware of each other's resources?

Answer (score 0):

> I found that the state stored on my local machine is version 3 whereas
>   the state stored in S3 bucket shows version 4, and the content is
>   different, could this be the issue?

Yes.

Make sure your states were produced by the same terraform version.

Comment: When I run ```Terraform 0.12upgrade```, it shows some errors, I've commented above in the question.

Comment: When I run ```terraform -version``` it shows
```Terraform v0.12.20
+ provider.archive v1.3.0
+ provider.aws v2.54.0```

Comment: IDENT means that you have a syntax error. Check if you close all parentheses, quotes and brackets properly. Make sure your tf code is valid.

Comment: It sounds very much like they are using the same state file for multiple configurations more than anything. If they fix this then they should address the separate issue of trying to run multiple Terraform versions but that should be raised as a separate question.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Hi thank you, I've solved the issue, it's because I should create a separate S3 bucket for storing the state, otherwise it's sharing the same one with the other repo, surprisingly it seems like it has nothing to do with the Terraform version.

Comment: You don't need a separate S3 bucket. Just a separate object in that S3 bucket. But if you want to structure your state in a separate S3 bucket for whatever reasons then that also works. For example we use different S3 buckets per AWS account but have multiple state files in each S3 bucket.